# what is the device name of the microphone in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, sound, microphone, devices

I want to redirect audio from a source like vlc media player to the microphone device.I would like to do it via the command-line, rather than using a GUI based software. what device should I be using?

I see this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82259/how-to-pipe-audio-output-to-mic-input

which is probably functionaly similar, but it uses a GUI, and doesnt tell me the `/dev/microphone` device. I looked around for intuitively named devices in /dev, but I didnt find it.